# FileOpenPicker not working windows phone 8.1 using phonegap

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to pick a file using FileOpenPicker in windows phone 8.1 by using phonegap, but its not working.

I use this code

`public class Echo : BaseCommand
    {
        public void echo(string options)
        {
            try{
                FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
                openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
                openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
                StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                if (file != null){
                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Picked photo: " + file.Name));
                }
                else{
                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Operation cancelled"));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Error=>"+e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }`

In phonegap

`cordova.exec(success, error, "Echo", "echo");
                function success(message) {
                    //upload_file(message);
                    alert(message);
                }
                function error(e) {
                    alert(e);
                }`

But i am getting error like this

[image]

can anyone guide me.....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you got any solution please. i also facing same issue....

Comment: I am facing this issue, have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes MSDN documentation can be very messy.

```
PickSingleFileAsync(); // is not supported
```

Instead try this:

```
PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

[MSDN PickSingleFileAndContinue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.picksinglefileandcontinue.aspx)

---

[image]

Comment: I have tried to use PickSingleFileAndContinue, but it is failing with error : invalid action. any solution?